Cannot run Ocsigen app: "...ocsigenserver/var/run/ocsigenserver_command. I will continue without."
I'm on macOS Sonoma (M2), with ocaml 5.2.0 etc installed via opam (not using Homebrew). Then wanted to give Ocsigen a try.
First install ocsigen:
opam install ocsigenserver

Then create the project:
dune init project mysite

Adjust the dune file:
(executable
 (public_name mysite)
 (name main)
 (libraries
  ocsigenserver
  ocsigenserver.ext.staticmod))

The rest can be found on this page. Calling dune exec mysite failed:
$ dune exec mysite
mysite: ocsigen:main: Cannot create the command pipe /Users/andretampubolon/.opam/5.2.0-flambda/lib/ocsigenserver/var/run/ocsigenserver_command. I will continue without.: Unix.Unix_error(Unix.ENOENT, "mkfifo", "/Users/andretampubolon/.opam/5.2.0-flambda/lib/ocsigenserver/var/run/ocsigenserver_command")

Here's my repo. What's wrong here?

Does that path /Users/andretampubolon/.../run/ocsigenserver_command exist? Or, rather I suspect the directory it is supposed to be created in. It looks like it is trying to run mkfifo to create that as a pipe, so it could be permissions or missing/incorrect directories.

@RichardHuxton Nope. Inside ~/.opam/5.2.0-flambda/lib/ocsigenserver/var, there are only 3 folders: lib, log, and www

If you create the ../run subdirectory is it happy then?
